# Logout Feature in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am currently in the process of learning the Spring Framework and I am building a small simple application which user's can login to something and logout to the main page. 
I have utilised Spring's logout functionality and made it redirect to the home page after the user had clicked 'Logout'. This works well and it seems to work, because when I try access a restricted path it displays the login page again, which essentially is good.

Although, when the user had logged out and gets redirected to the main page and presses the
'back' button on the browser, it seems to go back to the restricted area. How do I stop this from occurring?

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: What is your login mechanism? Do you use Filter or sping securty? what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the browser has cached the previous page. If you want to prevent this from happening, you'll need to disable caching of the pages in the secured area. Consider the overall design of your system (are you using lots of AJAX, or is content embedded in the main HTML) in deciding what cache policy to apply.

Comment: Content at the moment is embedded into the HTML. How do I resolve this issue for now? I think I will apply AJAX to it later.

Comment: @MatthewBobrowski Then just set a `Cache-Control` header to prevent the browser from caching any content, or set a very short `Expires` header to allow the user a quick Back button but still clear out the pages a few seconds after logout.

Comment: On what page though? And you mean the meta tag ones? Or putting cache control into a bean?

Comment: @MatthewBobrowski Put `Cache-Control` or `Expires` on *all* of the secured pages so that the browser won't keep copies. These are headers; you *could* put them in `meta` tags, but the best approach is to set them in the HTTP response as HTTP headers.